# Euler Totient Function- proof of $\phi(n) = n(1-1/p_1)(1-1/p_2)...(1-1/p_k)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Now I have come across a proof of the function using the inclusion-exclusion principle however it isn't so clear how they easily have factorized in the end to get $m(1-\frac{1}{p_1})(1-\frac{1}{p_2})$... etc. where the input of the function is $m$. I have done this for actual numbers and can see how it all fits into place nicely but the factorization doesn't seem so obvious to me for a general number.

Sorry if I'm slightly vague.

Comment: Can you write up the argument so that others can look at it? As is, any helpful answer would first have to guess the exact proof you've seen.

Comment: First you prove that IF $\gcd(a,b) = 1,$ THEN $\phi(ab) = \phi(a) \phi(b)$

Comment: will jaggy im not proving the multiplicative property just yet, well i can kind of write the argument here but I can't use the latex here very well, ill give it a try so here goes: say m=p1^a1*p2^a2......pn^an where the primes are all distinct we can say the euler totient function of m is m-((m/p1+m/p2+.....m/pn)-(m/p1p2+m/p1p3....)+....) so i can see you can factorise m out thats fine, but how can i easily go from the brackets with the primes to (1-1/p1)(1-1/p2)... etc quickly, hope this helps

Comment: @Whiz , if you type the "at" sign @, followed immediately by the beginning of my name (I think you need to do the capital W, not sure)   it should open a tiny window above the comment and allow you to click on my full correct name as this website uses it. That way I will be informed of any comments you make that are intended for me. I was not informed of your comments above, i just happened to check back.

Comment: @WhizKid, apparently a lower case w would also work

Comment: Anyway, maybe you should focus a little bit on primes and prime powers; So, Exercises, what are $\phi(2), \phi(4), \phi(8);$ then what are $\phi(3), \phi(9), \phi(27);$ then what are $\phi(5), \phi(25), \phi(125).$

Comment: @WillJagy i can do tht, I have already seen the pattern for numbers which are prime composite etc. I'm just stuck how to factorise the expression 1-((1/p1+1/p2....1/pn)-(1/p1p2+1/p1p3......)) into (1-1/p1)(1-1/p2)...(1-1/pn) the factorisation for me doesnt seem so obvious and wanted to know the best way to see it/prove it without going the other way.

Comment: In $\prod\limits_{k=1}^m \left(1 - \frac{1}{p_k}\right)$, the term $\dfrac{1}{p_{n_1}\cdot \dotsc \cdot p_{n_r}}$ occurs with sign $(-1)^r$. Is that where your problems lie?

Comment: @DanielFischer yes, thats the area where i need help in. I get the sign stuff, I guess I can easily go from the product to the summation and but I can't easily see how would someone go from the summation to the product without knowing they were equivalent before.

Comment: Perhaps they went from the product to the sum (in similar situations) often enough to recognise it. Perhaps they tackled it from an altogether different angle, perhaps Euler was just a genius. Well, the last is certainly true, but I don't know if it's relevant here. I guess it's practice.

Comment: @DanielFischer I guess its practice and recognition because I find it very difficult how someone would go from the summation to the product easily. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

First If you want to talk about a particular proof I think that it'll be wiser to post a link here to the proof or at least try to copy it and then ask about the part that's unclear to you.

I don't know much about the inclusion-exclusion way to prove, but you can look at this proof.

First of all I want you to understand what's Euler Totient function is all about. Euler Totient function is an arithmetic function that will count the number of totatives of a given number $n$. To make it more clear, totatives of $n$ are numbers that are coprime to $n$ and are smaller than or equal to $n$

Before you can continue the proof you need to prove that $\phi(n)$ is a multiplicative function, i.e. if $gcd(a,b) = 1$, the $\phi(ab) = \phi(a) \cdot \phi(b)$. I'll leave this part to you

Now to make it clearer how it works let $p_k$ be a prime number of $n$, then there are $\frac {p_k}{p_k}$ numbers that have $p_k$ as a factor, so those number aren't coprime to $p_k$, so we need to subtract them.

We know that there are $p_k$ integers smaller that or equal to $p_k$, so we have:

$$p_k - \frac {p_k}{p_k} = p_k\left(1-\frac{1}{p_k}\right)$$

So after this move we excluded all numbers that have $p_k$ as as factor. Note that this works for every number, because this will lead that there are $p_k - 1$ totatives to $p_k$, which is obviously true.

If we have a prime power, then there are obviously $\frac{p_k^{a_k}}{p_k}$ integers that aren't comprime to $p_k$. So after subtracting we have:

$$p_k^{a_k} - \frac{p_k^{a_k}}{p_k} = p_k^{a_k}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_k}\right)$$

Now assuming that you proved that $\phi(n)$ is multiplicative we can make the final step:

Let $n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}...p_k^{a_k}$, beacuse $\phi(n)$ is multiplicative we can rewrite it using this property, beacuse $p_1, p_2...p_k$ are all prime numbers, so it implies that they are compime:

$$\phi(n) = \phi(p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}...p_k^{a_k}) = \phi(p_1^{a_1})\phi(p_2^{a_2})...\phi(p_k^{a_k})$$

Using the property for prime powers we proved before we have:

$$\phi(n) = p_1^{a_1}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_1}\right) p_2^{a_2}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_2}\right)...p_k^{a_k}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_k}\right)$$

$$\phi(n) = p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}...p_k^{a_k}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_1}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{p_2}\right)...\left(1-\frac{1}{p_k}\right)$$

$$\phi(n) = n\left(1-\frac{1}{p_1}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{p_2}\right)...\left(1-\frac{1}{p_k}\right)$$

And finally we reached the wanted form of the Euler Totient function.